# Do I have to split a controller with multiple endpoints which represent the CRUD operations of components of a more complex object?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have at the moment an object (let's call it ComplexObj) composed by 10 different objects and I need to create a REST controller or several to handle CRUD operations for ComplexObj and also for its 10 different objects individually.

I have been researching and what people talk about is to split them if they have a completely different business logic. In this case the objects of ComplexObj have a slightly different business logic but as they are 10 I feel that create 10 (controller per object) + 1 (controller for ComplexObj) would be too many.

```
public class ComplexObj {
    private ObjA objA;
    private ObjB objB;
    private ObjC objC;
    private ObjD objD;
    private ObjE objE;
    private ObjF objF;
    private ObjG objG;
    private ObjH objH;
    private ObjI objI;
}
```

One of the use case I have is, the ComplexObj will be created if it does not exist when the endpoint save ObjA is hit.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's where the idea of creating different microservices comes into the picture.
It depends on how ComplexObj, ObjA, ObjB... is seen from a business segregation perspective.

So if ObjA and ObjB are two different unrelated resources in business terms, two different microservice with different endpoints must be created.

Now, let's say ComplexObj is a resource which comprises of ObjA and ObjB, it should call the downstream microservices of ObjA and ObjB to perform CRUD operations.

Comment: The project in my company is monolithic, they want to create ComplexObj when ObjA controller is called. 
I feel it is breaking a hierarchy rule and beside getting a tight relationship between Obj[A-Z] to ComplexObj, so if in the future we want to get rid of it, we will have to delete code from the controller or service of ObjA, ObjB... that's why I came to here to ask because the idea I had was to create a controller for ComplexObj, so first you check if exist and if not you create it and then call the controller of ObjA and inject it with the ID of the new ComplexObj . 
How do you see it?

Comment: Given it's the monolithic model, it seems the right approach. I am assuming you already have a service layer in place for ObjA which should be reused in ComplexObj controller for any operations dealing with ObjA. Also, have a separate service of ComplexObj.

Comment: Thank you very much @deadzg_devil. Last question if you do not mind, the ComplexObj service should be the one which calls ObjA service and ObjB service or should be the controller of ComplexObj which calls ObjA service and ObjB service and the ComplexObj service should be used only for specific actions for itself?

Comment: I am assuming ObjA, ObjB has its own data transformation layer/business segregation, thus it's better to inject dependencies of these services layers in the ComplexObj controller. 
But this approach can be challenged given the coupling of ObjA/B with ComplexObj and how these objects are going to be extended/used in the future. You may need to take a pragmatic approach here.

Answer (score 1):

The design of REST end points depends upon the business domain. There is no hard and fast rule to make one or more end points. It is all about how you design for smooth running of your application. Each REST end point with a controller should be very cohesive. Let us consider an example that organisation, each organization may have many departments, each department may have many employees, each employee will have addresses and so on. Technically you can design only one REST end point to address this, but it will not be a good design. First of all you have address that how many organisations are there and one REST end point should address about organisation details with its ids. The next REST end point should address the departments with org id and so on. If you observe this example, our Organisation object will be more complex as it will have Departments, each department will have Employee as object and so on.

You can also think like this, why we do not maintain only one database, why do we maintain multiple database tables with relation. To substantiate, I say that your each REST end point should provide a very specific information rather than all information. There can be a very large complex object for specific information as per the business requirements.

In this context, I say, you have to design multiple REST end points for specific information. It should not be based upon the size of the object, it should be specific to business use cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Sambit, the point you are giving actually makes a lot of sense. Actually I think I will try to push in my company to start moving sooner rather than later the project to micro services, otherwise our Controller module is going to become huge.